# Aspect-oriented programming library for C#

Tags: library, software-development, c#, .net, framework

I'm looking for an actively-developed C# framework for Aspect-Oriented Programming. It seems like there are lots of choices for Java, but I've been struggling to find a good, free choice for C#.

PostSharp seems like a reasonable choice, but it costs $400, which is a lot given that this is still just a demo.

The closest I've been able to find for an answer so far is [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434183/what-aspect-oriented-programming-aop-libraries-for-net-are-still-actively-dev?rq=1), but it's about 4 years old at this point and seems quite out-of-date; for example, it lists [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/index.html) as being under active development, even though the last announcement I see on the framework's web site is from December 2012, so I'm assuming that it's no longer under active development (correct me if I'm wrong).

Does anyone have any recommendations?